# MySQL search multiple fields and sort results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a structure like this:

**users Table**

```
ID |  firstname  | lastname   | email
________________________________________________
 1 |  Carl       | Andersson  | carl@site.se
 2 |  Carl       | Smith      | smith@site.se
 3 |  Eve        | Carlow     | carlow@site.se
 4 |  Randy      | Smith      | randy@site.se
```

I need a search function that allows me to search all fields. 
I've tried using statements like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%" . $KEYWORD . "%' OR lastname LIKE '%" . $KEYWORD . "%' OR email LIKE '%" . $KEYWORD . "%'";
```

Above works, but the resulting list isn't ordered correctly according to relevance.

**Example 1**

If a user search for "Carl Andersson" there will be no match since first and last name is stored in different fields.

I also tried using REGEXP like this:

```
$KEYWORD = str_replace (" ", "|", $KEYWORD); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname REGEXP '%" . $KEYWORD . "%' OR lastname REGEXP '%" . $KEYWORD . "%' OR email REGEXP '%" . $KEYWORD . "%'";
```

**Example 2**

If a user searches for "Carl Smith" both user 1, 2, 3 will show up. But the relevance order will be wrong. ID 1 will show up first since this entry is the one thats found first.

**Question:** 
How can I search all fields without missing hits and preserve the relevance order?

Comment: Not sure but your question and answer appeared to be posted at the same time !! So is that a question ??

Comment: Not anymore, Since I solved it, But since It took me a while to figure out I thought I would share the solution!

Comment: I see !! I got confused since when the page is loaded there was an answer with it, so I asked, never-mind !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using mysql Fulltext index match.

**Step 1:**
Add fulltext index to the concerned fields

```
ALTER TABLE  users  
ADD FULLTEXT(firstname, lastname, email);
```

**Step 2:** 
Search using MATCH() AGAINST()

```
$query = "SELECT productName, productline FROM products WHERE MATCH(firstname, lastname, email) AGAINST('Carl Smith')";
```

This method auto sorts hits according to relevance.

**Pittfalls**

1. For this method to work your table need to be of myISAM type, NOT
   InnoDB
2. The search query must be at least 4 characters long or else
   no match will be returned.

**Workaround**

You could use query expansion to search for shorter keywords or use MATCH() AGAINST() IN BOOLEAN MODE. This allowing you to add asterisks(*) to pad your string to a valid length.

More reading on FULLTEXT search: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspxmysql